# Convert number to month name?

Tags: excel

I have this formula:

```
DQ11=DATE("20"&LEFT(DN18;2);1;-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE("20"&LEFT(DN18;2);1;3))+RIGHT(DN18;2)*7
```

which gives the number 41519.

For reference:

```
DN18 = 1336
```

Now I want to convert 41519 to a month name. How do I do that? I've tried:

```
=TEXT(DQ11;"mmm")
```

but it returns 00.

Comment: What month would '41519' be?

Comment: Sample data would also help what is in DN18?

Comment: 41519 is the Excel datecode for September 2, 2013.  Try changing the cell format of DQ11 to be `mmm` and it should display `Sep`

Comment: I tried your exact code `=Text(D1, "mmm")` where D1 was the 41519 value and I got `Sep`... I don't know why I didn't work for you...

Comment: I still haven't managed to figure this out.

Comment: Try to see if you have any trailing or preceding zeros. and also that semicolon should be a comma.

Comment: Nope, I even tried it in a new Excel workbook, typing all the numbers from scratch. Could it be due to localization of the Excel version or something like that?

Comment: =TEXT(DQ11;"ddd") gives me the day

Comment: I noticed you're using semicolons for function parameter delimiters instead of commas; what version of Excel and localization are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparantly Text(DQ11;"MMM") gives me what I want.

I don't know why mmm didn't work and hope that my code will work on other vesions of Excel.

Comment: In some excel versions (including yours apparently) "mmm" will be interpreted as **minutes** not months, so you need the upper case version MMM for months. test by trying =TEXT(NOW(),"mmm") - the number you get should be the current time minutes, e.g. it's 8:42 here so I would get 42. This doesn't happen in English/US versions